# C++ const member function returns a pointer

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

Is it considered bad practice to mark a method as const even though the (pointer) data member it returns could be used "outside" the method to change its referenced object?

Take a look at the bone() method.

```
class SceneNode
{
public:
    SceneNode(const char *nodeName, SceneNode *parent);
    ~SceneNode();

    void setBone(Bone *bone);
    Bone* bone() const { return _bone; }
};

private:
    Bone *_bone;
};
```

I'm asking this because it's seems a little weird to me as the method can't be const if _bone wasn't a pointer, but an object (unless it returns a const reference or copy, of course).

Comment: It depends on your use case, but in this one, it makes more sense to return `const Bone*`.

Comment: This is definitely a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I do want to be able to change the referenced object of _bone. I'm asking if it's bad practice to set the method as const

Comment: @user657267 Why is that? It's perfectly correct, as the method doesn't change _bone itself but allows its content to be modified by the caller. Did you mean that it's just bad practice?

Comment: Depends on who owns `_bone`. `const` trailing a method means that calling the method will have no effect on the object. If the object has ownership of `_bone`, allowing changes to `_bone` violates the contract. And careful with the underscore prefix. They often mean special things in the c++ standard.

Comment: @Pilpel The semantics of the class suggest that `SceneNode` owns the bone (I could be wrong of course), I wouldn't want a constant node's content to change in any way at all.

Comment: It does own the bone.

Comment: if it owns the bone then you should consider having the `Bone` stored as an object, or through a `unique_ptr`

Comment: So from what I understand, it makes sense to set the method to const only if the class doesn't own the pointed object. Am I right?

Comment: @Pilpel You need to think of `const` in terms of a an abstract contract, i.e. "This node cannot be modified through this function". The bone clearly can be modified, which might not affect the `SceneNode` object at a c++ level, but your scene would change if this were to happen.

Comment: @RyanHaining You're right, however, in my code there could be cases when a SceneNode doesn't hold a bone, and then _bone=nullptr.

Comment: @Pilpel then use a `unique_ptr`

Comment: @Pilpel There's also [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) if your library supports it, or [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I don't have std::experimental::optional in VC++ 2010. Is it C++11 or something?

Comment: @Pilpel It's definitely not in VC 2010. It's part of a library [Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions) which means it isn't even part of the main standard (hence `experimental`). `boost::optional` is pretty much the same thing, the standard's version is probably based on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It depends**
For example, [`unique_ptr::operator*()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) is marked as const but doesn't add an additional const to the reference it returns.  This makes sense because it's analogous to being able to modify what is pointed to by a `T *const` but not change the pointer itself.

```
const std::unique_ptr<int> uptr(new int); // make_unique is better
*uptr = 1; // sure, I can modify what it points to
uptr.reset(); // no, this modifies the pointer itself (conceptually)
```

On the other hand, something like `std::string` having `char& operator[](size_t) const;` would be weird because the `char`s inside of it should act like part of the object they are referenced by (the `string` class)

```
const std::string s{"hello world"}; // I expect this to always be "hello world"
s[0] = 'a'; // error, you're conceptually modifying the string
```

It's up to you to decide what makes sense in your API and when your class is "morally const".  If you had

```
void fun(const SceneNode& node);
int main() {
    SceneNode n(...);
    Bone b;
    n.setBone(&b);
    fun(n);
    assert(*n.bone() == b); // is this a safe assumption?
}
```

If you think that assertion should always hold, then return a `const Bone*`.

Comment: To "solve" your last code issue, I could just add a second method? `const Bone* bone() const { return _bone; }`. This will assure that `node` in fun will always call the const version? (and therefore a change to `b` will never occur)

Comment: @Pilpel right. that's the common way, just like you have `T& operator[](size_t);` and `const T& operator[](size_t) const` in containers like vector

Answer (score 2):

Setting `const` on the method results in *well-defined* behavior, but it may still be *confusing* behavior. Whether or not it's confusing depends on what the class is supposed to represent and what mental model a programmer is supposed to have.

For a similar example, consider `std::vector`. This class also has a data member that is a pointer, and it has a method to retrieve that pointer; e.g. something like

```
template< typename T >
class vector
{
    T *elements;
public:
    T* data() { return elements; }
};
```

What about a `const` version? Well, the thing that an instance of this class represents would be changed if you modified what the pointer refers to; i.e. if you change an element of the vector, then you've changed the vector. Consequently, a const version should not return a pointer to non-const:

```
template< typename T >
class vector
{
    T *elements;
public:
    T* data() { return elements; }
    const T* data() const { return elements; }
};
```

On the other hand, consider `std::shared_ptr` also has a data member that is a pointer, and has a method to retrieve that pointer:

```
template< typename T >
class shared_ptr
{
    T *ptr;
public:
    T* get() { return ptr; }
};
```

What if we get the pointer and change what it points to? Well, we haven't changed the `shared_ptr` at all: it's *still* pointing to that object. So in this case, we should have

```
template< typename T >
class shared_ptr
{
    T *ptr;
public:
    T* get() const { return ptr; }
};
```